# nativescript-ui / RadListView : getting item index from scroll offset

Tags: nativescript-telerik-ui, radlistview

The RadListView exposes some listeners on scroll events. The corresponding event data contains only the new scroll offset of the list, using dips unit.
Is there a way to get a corresponding item index in the data source for this physical position ?